# Como garantir que três condições sejam satisfeitas? Há uma maneira melhor de fazer?

Tags: python, algoritmo

Programa que pergunta a idade, o peso e a altura de uma pessoa e decide se ela está apta a entrar pro exército. Para entrar, é preciso maior de idade, pesar mais ou igual 60 quilos e medir mais ou igual 1,70 metros.

```
print('='*5, 'Aliste-se no Exército Brasileiro', '='*5)

idade = int(input('Digite sua idade: '))
peso = int(input('Digite seu peso: '))
altura = float(input('Digite sua altura: ex:1.7 '))

apto = ' '

if idade >= 18:
    apto = '1'
else:
    apto = '0'

if peso >= 60:
    apto += '1'
else:
    apto += '0'

if altura >= 1.70:
    apto += '1'
else:
    apto += '0'

if apto == '111':
    print('Você está apto a alista-se no exército brasileiro, parabéns.')
elif apto == '011':
    print('Você não possue Idade sulficiente para ingressar no exército.')
elif apto == '101':
    print('Você não possue peso sulficiente para ingressar no exército.')
elif apto == '110':
    print('Você não possue altura sulficiente para ingressar no exército.')
elif apto == '100':
    print('Você não possue nem Peso nem Altura sulficiente para ingressar no exército.')
elif apto == '001':
    print('Você não possue nem Idade nem Peso sulficiente para ingressar no exército.')
elif apto == '010':
    print('Você não possue nem Idade nem Altura sulficiente para ingressar no exército.')
else:
    print('Você não possui nenhum dos requisitos para entrar no Exército')
```

Answer (score 2):

A ideia é apenas verificar se está apto ou não a partir de 3 condições. Para tal, ao invés de criar uma *string* com três valores e depois verificar todas as possibilidades, você pode usar a função `all`:

```
idade = int(input('Sua idade: '))
peso = float(input('Seu peso: '))
altura = float(input('Sua altura: '))

apto = all([
    idade >= 18,
    peso >= 60,
    altura >= 1.70
])
```

Assim, `apto` será `True` quando as três condições forem satisfeitas ou `False` em todos os outros casos.

---

Dada a nova informação que as mensagens também são necessárias, o que você pode fazer é algo como:

```
idade = int(input('Sua idade: '))
peso = float(input('Seu peso: '))
altura = float(input('Sua altura: '))

apto = True

if idade < 18:
    print('Você precisa ter, pelo menos, 18 anos')
    apto = False

if peso < 60:
    print('Você precisa ter, pelo menos, 60 quilos')
    apto = False

if altura < 1.70:
    print('Você precisa ter, pelo menos, 1.70 m de altura')
    apto = False

if apto:
    print('parabéns, você está apto a alistar-se')
```

Ao final, se alguma condição não for satisfeita, `apto` será `False`.

Comment: É, mas eu esqueci de relatar q é preciso informar no script em que quesito o candidato (ao exército) falha, idade, peso ou altura ou duas das ou as três...

Comment: Silas, e precisa ser em apenas um texto ou podem ser múltiplas mensagens? Por favor, edite a sua pergunta e adicione este detalhe no enunciado.

Comment: Não. Agora, está perfeito! rsrs.

Answer (score 0):

Pegando a idéia do Anderson Carlos Woss:

```
print('='*5, 'Aliste-se no Exército Brasileiro', '='*5)
idade = int(input('Sua idade: '))
peso = float(input('Seu peso: '))
altura = float(input('Sua altura: '))
printe = ''
apto = True
if idade < 18:
    printe = 'Você precisa ter, pelo menos, 18 anos'
    apto = False
if peso < 60:
    printe += '\nVocê precisa ter, pelo menos, 60 quilos'
    apto = False
if altura < 1.70:
    printe += '\nVocê precisa ter, pelo menos, 1.70 m de altura'
    apto = False
nenhum_requisito = all([
    idade < 18,
    peso < 60,
    altura < 1.70
])
if nenhum_requisito:
   printe ='Você não possui nenhum dos quesitos para se alistar!'
if apto == True:
    printe = 'parabéns, você está apto a alistar-se'
print(printe)
```

OU TALVEZ:

```
print('='*5, 'Aliste-se no Exército Brasileiro', '='*5)
idade = int(input('Sua idade: '))
peso = float(input('Seu peso: '))
altura = float(input('Sua altura: '))
printe = ''
nenhum_requisito = ''
apto = True
if idade < 18:
    printe = 'Você precisa ter, pelo menos, 18 anos'
    apto = False
if peso < 60:
    printe += '\nVocê precisa ter, pelo menos, 60 quilos'
    apto = False
if altura < 1.70:
    printe += '\nVocê precisa ter, pelo menos, 1.70 m de altura'
    apto = False
if idade < 18 and peso < 60 and altura < 1.70:
    nenhum_requisito = 'Você não possui nenhum dos quesitos para se alistar!'
    printe = nenhum_requisito
if apto == True:
    printe = 'parabéns, você está apto a alistar-se'
print(printe)
```

Não sei qual o melhor script, apostaria no primeiro. Se alguém poder avaliar...